# What is the equivalent of Java charAt() in Swift?

Tags: java, swift, string

I am solving counting valleys problem in interview preparation website. How can I traverse my string characters like Java in Swift:

**Java:**

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
 if (s.charAt(i) == 'A') { }
}
```

**Swift:**

```
for i in 0...n {
  if (s.???? == "A") {}
}
```

I looked [Cannot find char at position and index of char of a string var in Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391777/cannot-find-char-at-position-and-index-of-char-of-a-string-var-in-swift-2?noredirect=1) but all answers are writing extension to `String`.

How can I write like Java `charAt()` shortly in Swift?

Comment: I do not understand anything from your answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get nth character of a string in Swift programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language)

Comment: `print(countingHills(n: 8, s: "DDDUUUDD"))`is test case. I have to traverse s parameter with for loop like `s.charAt(i)`

Comment: @Scheff I guess it's a task [Counting Valleys](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/counting-valleys/problem)

Comment: Yes, it is. But how can I write `charAt(i)` in swift?

Comment: @Dávid: Regarding your comment at Joakim's (now deleted) answer: `String` is a collection, but not an array of `Character`, so `Array(s)` is *not* useless.

Comment: Dávid closed my question but I do not find the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language. Thank you Dávid!

Comment: Don't translate programs between languages word for word. Java and Swift are completely different languages. Good, clean, conventional code in one would be an absolute disaster in another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the equivalent of an "enhanced" loop:

```
for c in s {
    if(c == 'A') ...
}
```